# Specify offline time between login time and logout time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have been working in a project to create schedule adherence, I already have order the real time and the schedule time to get the percentage between those two. But I found a roadblock in the real time. There are some employees that take their lunch offline from their phone instead of setting an auxiliary status. Here is an example:

```
CCMS ID | Exception | LoginTime | LogoutTime | LogoutDate
--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------
2747738 | Open      | 09:31:00  | 12:25:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | AUX 1     | 12:25:00  | 12:35:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | Open      | 12:35:00  | 14:00:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | Open      | 15:00:00  | 16:35:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | AUX 8     | 16:35:00  | 16:38:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | Open      | 16:38:00  | 17:30:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | AUX 1     | 17:30:00  | 17:40:00   | 2018-06-19
2747738 | Open      | 17:40:00  | 18:33:00   | 2018-06-19
```

As you can see from above, there is unaccounted for time.  Notice that there is no entry to account for time between 14:00 and 15:00.  What I am trying to accomplish is to account for all time, kind of like below. Here you can see that there is a new "Open" entry made from 14:00 to 15:00 so that all time throughout the day is accounted for:

```
  CCMS ID | Exception | LoginTime | LogoutTime | LogoutDate
  --------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------
  2747738 | Open      | 09:31:00  | 12:25:00   | 2018-06-19
  2747738 | AUX 1     | 12:25:00  | 12:35:00   | 2018-06-19
  2747738 | Open      | 12:35:00  | 14:00:00   | 2018-06-19
  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
>>2747738 | Open      | 14:00:00  | 15:00:00   | 2018-06-19<< Created entry here
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  2747738 | Open      | 15:00:00  | 16:35:00   | 2018-06-19
  2747738 | AUX 8     | 16:35:00  | 16:38:00   | 2018-06-19
  2747738 | Open      | 16:38:00  | 17:30:00   | 2018-06-19
  2747738 | AUX 1     | 17:30:00  | 17:40:00   | 2018-06-19
  2747738 | Open      | 17:40:00  | 18:33:00   | 2018-06-19
```

I am looking to accomplish this with your knowledge.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not submit questions with the data attached in images.  Over time, the images can become unavailable and seriously degrade the value of your question.

Comment: First time using StackOverflow to ask something

Comment: Understood.  No worries.

Comment: which database MSSQL, mysql ...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: It is for SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use MSSQL here is the solution (i name your table **T4**)

```
SELECT
    RES.[CCMS ID]
    , CASE WHEN U.[NR]=1 THEN '**hole**' ELSE RES.[Exception] END AS [Exception]
    , CASE WHEN U.[NR]=1 THEN  RES.[LogoutTime] ELSE RES.[LoginTime] END AS [LoginTime]
    , CASE WHEN U.[NR]=1 THEN  RES.[B LoginTime] ELSE RES.[LogoutTime] END AS [LogoutTime] 
    , RES.[LogoutDate] 
FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2
) U(NR)
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
    A.[CCMS ID], A.[Exception], A.[LoginTime], A.[LogoutTime], A.[LogoutDate] 
    ,B.[CCMS ID] AS [B CCMS ID], B.[Exception] AS [B Exception], B.[LoginTime] AS [B LoginTime], B.[LogoutTime] AS [B LogoutTime], B.[LogoutDate] AS [B LogoutDate] 
    ,CASE WHEN A.[LogoutTime]<>B.[LoginTime] THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS [hole]
    FROM
    T4 A
    LEFT JOIN T4 B ON 
        B.[CCMS ID]=A.[CCMS ID] 
        AND B.[LogoutDate]=A.[LogoutDate] 
        AND B.[LoginTime]>A.[LoginTime] 
        AND NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT * FROM T4 C WHERE 
            C.[CCMS ID]=B.[CCMS ID] 
            AND C.[LogoutDate]=B.[LogoutDate] 
            AND C.[LoginTime]<B.[LoginTime]
            AND C.[LoginTime]>A.[LoginTime]
          )
    ) RES ON 
            CASE WHEN RES.[hole]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END=U.[NR]
            OR
            CASE WHEN RES.[hole] IN (1,2) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END=U.[NR]


CCMS ID Exception   LoginTime   LogoutTime  LogoutDate
2747738 Open    09:31:00.0000000    12:25:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 AUX 1   12:25:00.0000000    12:35:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 **hole**    14:00:00.0000000    15:00:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 Open    12:35:00.0000000    14:00:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 Open    15:00:00.0000000    16:35:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 AUX 8   16:35:00.0000000    16:38:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 Open    16:38:00.0000000    17:30:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 AUX 1   17:30:00.0000000    17:40:00.0000000    2018-06-19
2747738 Open    17:40:00.0000000    18:33:00.0000000    2018-06-19
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0c23/24/0